# Fixed position but moves with container

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-position

I have a draggable container and some draggable items in it. The deal is: I want items to move with container when I drag (move around) the container. My container is absolute positioned and my items are fixed positioned. (Relative position for items causing some problems, that's why I'm using fixed position for items).

Example code:

```js
<div class="container-fluid area draggable ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="left: 714px; top: 194px;">
   <div class="toolbar-item draggable ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle toolbar-item-out" id="i1_num1" style="color: red; position: fixed !important; top: 584.98px; left: 910.492px;"> item 2 </div>
   <div class="toolbar-item draggable ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle toolbar-item-out" id="i1_num0" style="color: red; position: fixed !important; top: 346.992px; left: 845.492px;"> item 2 </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible  to solve this?

Note: "area" class has "position: absolute !important" in it.

Comment: Position fixed is relative to the containing block which by default is the viewport. You can change the containing block. [This should help.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block) You could also try making the children of the draggable element have position absolute. That way the draggable element will act as their containing block since it has a position different to static.

Comment: Your draggable container has a position absolute relative to the browser hasn't it? and the items within the draggable container have a fixed position they are not fixed relative to your draggable container maybe you need one another div with a relative position within your draggable container the move your items with a fixed position inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Thanks to [Benjamin Rae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18474704/benjamin-rae) for the comment.

Apparently there is 2 solutions for this.

### First way

is making both your parent and child `position: absolute;`. I dont know how didn't I thought about that but it was simple as that.

### Second Way

is turning your child `position: fixed;` to `position: sticky;`. Then you'll add `overflow: auto;` to your parent.